# Error AADSTS50012: Client is public so a 'client_assertion' should not be presented

Tags: azure, certificate, token

I am getting this error when trying to generate AAD token from clientid and certificate using below code.

> Error: "AADSTS50012: Client is public so a 'client_assertion' should
>   not be presented  Native app"

Code: `await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, assertionCert);`

Answer (score 22):

I found the the resolution for this.

I was registering my app as Native app in AAD. App should have been registered as WebApp