# Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow (PKCE) - Error "AADSTS700025"

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization

Trying to get access token by following the microsoft instructions.But I get an error, for that there is no answer with a solution.
What am I doing wrong, what this mean in my situation?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeffv.png)
Requests:
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)
*auth_code : client_id & response_type & redirect_uri & response_mode & scope & code_challenge & code_challenge_method.

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)
*get access token: client_id & scope & code & redirect_uri & grant_type & code_verifier & client_secret.(Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
redirect_uri  == are the same in both cases.

In the first request it is possible to get auth_code, but when i trying to get access token with this auth_code then I get : Error "AADSTS700025" Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented.
But I use client_secret NOT client_assertion_type & client_assertion.
Followed the microsoft instructions...

Comment: Please check this thread it may help to you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219139/error-aadsts50012-client-is-public-so-a-client-assertion-should-not-be-presen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Reproduce the same kind of issue as you are facing (As i am using AuthCode to generate Access Token)***

[image]

***Solution--***

Aussming you are using `grant_type` is `client_credentials` to get the access token using below API:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

To get the **`access token`** you don't require the `AuthCode` you can get it by client credentails only. Please do the configuration as i did below picture in my Body.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is a 'SPA' type 'Platform' (as added within your 'AAD'/Azure AD 'app-registration'), or one of the other 'Public clients'?

It's likely telling you that the server does not want to deal with/trust a *public* client that is dealing with/privy to (potentially/more-likely susceptible) secrets (- such as 'client_secret' & 'client_assertion' values).

E.g.  If this was a 'Private/Confidential Client', you could add (& configure) the 'Web' type 'Platform' - because it is trusted to handle secrets, and (in theory) the error would no longer occur.